# How do I save standard output to a different text file everyday with file name as ( dd-mm-yy.txt )?

Tags: redis

In `redis`, the data is stored in one log file and it keeps getting bigger and bigger. Its size has increased to few GB. How can I store the log file as several files instead of one sorted by date?

Comment: # Specify the log file name. Also the empty string can be used to force
# Redis to log on the standard output. Note that if you use standard
# output for logging but daemonize, logs will be sent to /dev/null
logfile "/path/to/redis.log"

Comment: This is a part of the file "redis.conf" . The log file redis.log where all the data is stored it's size increases.So i want to store data everyday in a new file.How can i do this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `logrotate`:

Create a file `/etc/logrotate.d/redis` with something like this:

```
/var/log/redis/redis-server.log {
    daily
    rotate 12
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 root root
}
```

More configuration can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

**EDIT:** If you want a `dd-mm-yy` format you can use the `dateformat` directive as explain in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778444/2893600) response.